# Xamarin Android install APK programmatically StartActivity doesnt do anything

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-intent, xamarin.android

Hello i'm trying to install an apk programmatically.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="ABM.Ablesegeraet.Android">
    <provider 
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" 
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
        android:exported="false" 
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

other code:

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath + $"/com.companyname.abm.ablesegeraet.apk");
var downloadUri = Xamarin.Essentials.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".fileprovider", file);
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);  
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
install.SetDataAndType(downloadUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.StartActivity(install);
```

I don't get any errors but when context.StartActivity(install) is executed nothing happens.
What's the problem here?

//edit: this does not work in debug... In Release the activity does start but for some reasen it fails during the installation... It just says "App has not been installed" But why?

//edit2: to solve the "App has not been installed" error I had to delete the app and install it with a APK and not from visual studio. Also the update apk needs to have a higher build version than the installed one.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so  that we can test on our side?

Comment: I recommend to use the `PackageInstaller` API instead of launching intents to Install packages. Read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller